# Tracking file status changes in a Git log

Tags: git, diff, git-log

I'm writing a program that consumes `git log` output to walk a repository's history, and I want to know when files are added, deleted, copies, moved, or modified. `git log --numstat` is a straightforward way to see modifications, copies, and renames, but it doesn't provide a good way to differentiate added or deleted files from modifications. (When a file is added, `numstat` just shows as many lines added as there are in the file, and when one is deleted, as many lines removed.)

Reading the patch headers generated by `git log -p` gives me this information, but I don't care about the actual patch. Is there some way to only show the patch headers, or something similar?

Comment: git log --name-status ?

Comment: Yep! Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git log --name-status

```
   --name-status
       Show only names and status of changed files. See the description of the --diff-filter option on what the status letters mean.
```